# How to make stack of icons on a bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm having trouble trying to make a bar graph in Python but with the "bars" being stacks of images instead of rectangles. I was using matplotlib, but I couldn't find a feature similar to this one. Is there a method to do it? Even using another library?

Here's an example of what I want to generate:

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apply images to pyplot python bar graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066089/apply-images-to-pyplot-python-bar-graphs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525017/fill-images-repeatedly-on-bar-graph-bars-bars-customization):

```
fruits = {"Green": ["Grapes"],
          "Orange": ["Apricot", "Orange"],
          "Red": ["Strawberry", "Apple", "Cherry"],
          "Yellow": ["Banana"]}

for i, color in enumerate(fruits):
    for j, fruit_name in enumerate(fruits[color]):
        image = mpimg.imread(fruit_name)
        plt.imshow(image, extent=[i - 0.5, i + 0.5, j, j + 1])
```